# Lag and Performance Issues on iOS with Flutter App

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

1.**Issue 1:** Laggy screen on iOS App Store when opening the keyboard in a bottom sheet.

- im adjusting the position of the bottom sheet based on the keyboard visibility using `mediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`.

2. **Issue 2:** Experiencing lag when opening the keyboard on a regular screen with a search TextField. When popping back while the keyboard is still open, the entire screen gets re-rendered.
3. **Issue 3:** Experiencing slow movement on the chat page with the Scrollable Position List when the keyboard is open on iPhone. I attempted to change this package, thinking it might be the cause, but there were no noticeable changes.

**Additional Notes:**
Flutter version 3.16.5
Confirm that the issues are specific to iOS, Android is working fine.

I adjusted the bottom sheet position using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` when the keyboard opens. I expected smooth behavior, but on iOS, it resulted in significant lag.